# Python: Issue a warning when a module is imported from a (currently deprecated) location

Tags: python, python-module, python-import

We have an application that enables its users to extend it using plugins. We have provided some helper modules so from their plugins the users can access them using

```
import helpermodule
```

Now we have decided that it would be better to change the packaging of the helper modules so that all of them are loaded from a main package like this:

```
from ourpackage import helpermodule
```

Since we don't want to break the existent code in users plugins we still provide the old way. (In fact we've just imported the helper modules in the `__init__.py` file inside the `ourpackage` dir in our sources.) We would very much like to issue a warning (using the `warnings` standard library) when a user script imports the helper modules in the old way.

So my question is: Is there a way to tell if the user have imported a helper module in the "wrong" way? We would ideally like to achieve this without inspecting the user's code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are achieving the "still provide the old way".  It sounds like you are leaving the old modules directly on the search path and just doing `import helpermodule` inside ourpackage.  (That is, you yourself are still importing the module in the "wrong" way.)  In that case here is one possibility.

```
\dir_on_path
helper.py
    \ourpackage
        __init__.py

#### helper.py
import sys
if 'testpack' in sys.modules:
    print "Imported the good way"
else:
    print "Imported the bad way"
####

#### __init__.py
import teststuff
####
```

However, note that this way of doing it leaves some awkward problems.  You will not be able to do `import testpack.teststuff`.  Also, there remains the possibility that the person could import teststuff in both the good and bad ways, creating two separate copies in sys.modules.

If this isn't how you are "still providing the old way" please edit to clarify.